# What is the narrowest interval I=[a,b] such that there are infinitely prime gaps of size in I?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-constellations

Polymath8b project allowed, building on Zhang's 2013 breakthrough, to prove that there are infinitely prime gaps of size less or equal to 600. Under the generalized Elliott-Halberstam conjecture, one can reach the upper bound 6.

My question is: in early August 2016, what is the narrowest interval $I=[a,b]$ such that we know that there are infinitely many prime gaps whose size belongs to $I$?

I'm essentially interested in unconditional results, but those obtained under very plausible conjectures such as (G)EH and or (G)RH can be of some interest too.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: The twin prime conjecture is "very plausible" too...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should find [this wiki page useful.](http://michaelnielsen.org/polymath1/index.php?title=Bounded_gaps_between_primes) The current unconditional record is 246. Assuming Elliot Halberstam, the current record is 12, and assuming generalized Elliot Halberstam, the current record is 6.

[Here is the polymath paper.](http://arxiv.org/abs/1407.4897)